# $scope data in array format in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

A have test application on angular. I try receive data from php page in my model. The response come with this command  `echo  json_encode($arr);` from php file and has this format `[{"id":"1","name":"first","text":"description"}]`. To receive this data in my model need to use only query cause .get give an error. My query in controller:
 `$scope.item = Items.query({id:$routeParams.id});` 
Now if I want to use this data in my model i need to specify my array item[0].name
Thats not problem but when i try to save edited data

```
 $scope.item[0].$save({id:$scope.item[0].id});
```

i have an error TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the resource setup correctly, you should be able to save by simply calling:

```
$scope.item[0].$save();
```

However, it doesn't look like you are doing that.  When you use `query`, it normally return an array.  As you are querying for a single ID, you should really be using the `get` method:

```
$scope.item = Items.get({id:$routeParams.id});
...
// Modify $scope.item as needed
...
$scope.item.$save();
```

The simplest way to define a resource is to use default actions provided by Angular:

```
.factory('Items', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/angular/angular-seed/app/questions/php/maintext.php');
});
```

As per [Angular Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource):

```
The default set contains these actions:
{ 'get':    {method:'GET'},
  'save':   {method:'POST'},
  'query':  {method:'GET', isArray:true},
  'remove': {method:'DELETE'},
  'delete': {method:'DELETE'} };
```

Comment: I tried  but this give an error TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push' when the page is loading.

Comment: agree but same error TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  can't really tell here the problem might be without the rest of the code.  The push error is normally associated with $resource method set with isArray:true, but if you are using get you shouldn't be getting that error.

Comment: I think the problem might be in your `edit.html` where you are creating an array by setting `ng-model="item[0].name"`.  Are you actually getting the value you expected in the Edit page?  Change that to `ng-model="item.name"` and try again.

Comment: isArray: true in get method resolve the problem with init but same effect -  $scope.item[0].$save(); give error

Comment: yep ng-model="item[0].name" works good, ng-model="item.name" is empty and didnt give right data. that cause item is array

Comment: let's take this one step at a time... Remove the isArray: true from get and use ng-model="item.name".  In fact, leave your resource as `return $resource('/angular/angular-seed/app/questions/php/maintext.php');`.  Make sure you are not dealing with array at all in the EditCtrl.

Comment: Receive TypeError: Object #<Resource> has no method 'push'

Comment: That is really bizarre... Sorry to check the obvious but you did reload your browser to load the updated code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30215/discussion-between-socm-and-marcoseu)